# Как одновременно добавить класс к элементу, внутри которого другой элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой элемент списка :

```
<li class="listhover"> <a class="nav__link_footer" href="Quality.html" id="quality_footer"></a></li>
```

В зависимости страницы, текущей ссылке выдается класс `_active` следующим образом.

```
$(function($) {
   var path = window.location.href; 
$('.nav__link_footer').each(function() {
   if (this.href === path) {
   $(this).addClass('_active');
  }
 });
});
```

Так вот, здесь же есть элемент `li` с классом `linkhover`. Как сделать так, что когда у элемента а `nav__link_footer` статус `_active`, для элемента `li`  `linkhover`, в котором находится наш активный `nav__link_footer` выдавался статус `activelist`.

Наглядно:

Для неактивной ссылки:

```
<li class="listhover"> <a class="nav__link_footer" href="Quality.html" id="quality_footer"></a></li>
```

Для активной:

```
<li class="listhover activelist"> <a class="nav__link_footer _active" href="Quality.html" id="quality_footer"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чет гуглил неправильно видать. Нашел, что у JQuery есть метод:

`$(selector).parent()`.

В моем случае нужно просто добавить строчку:

`$(this).parent().addClass('activelist');`

Comment: Не нужно обновлять заголовок, добавляя в него `(решено)`. Достаточно нажать на галочку рядом с ответом, этим самым приняв его.

Comment: Пишет, что свой ответ смогу принять через 2 дня. Решил пока так)